# c# Select N elements from list uniformly without shuffle

Tags: c#, algorithm, list

I want to select K elements uniformly from a list of N elements without shuffling a list. So the algorithm should always produce the same result.

E.g.

```
int N = 100;

List<int> myList = Enumerable.Range(0, N-1).ToList();

int K = 20;
```

> Here i expect the result: `0, 5, 10, 15, 20, ...`
>
> E.g. `if K == 50` I expect: `0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...`

But I don't know how to solve it if e.g. K = 53?  I still want to take uniformly elements from the list, but in this case we can't simply take each second element from the list. Simple approach would be to shuffle elements and take first `K` elements from the list, order again the list but in that case the result of algorithm would each time produce different result and i need each time the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want same results I would use the Rand method a give a seed as a parameter.  The Rand method when no seed is provided uses the PC time as a seed to get different results each time.  Giving a seed will give the same random results each time for testing.

Comment: you could have at least posted your solution for `K == 20` and or `K == 50`

Comment: In case of 53 the list should contain exactly 53 elements that all have the same distance between prev and next?

Comment: @jdweng OP is not looking for random numbers. OP asks for a selection of equidistant #k - elements of the given list - if I understand that correctly.

Comment: My interpretation : " a list of N elements without shuffling a list to always produce the same result"

Comment: @jdweng you are missing the word "**uniformly**".

Comment: @BradleyUffner. Whilst he did say uniformly, he also said that shuffling it would theoretically be an option, so difficult to say really...

Comment: He also says that for `N=100` and `k=50`, the result should be EXACTLY `0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...`.  He says that shuffling would be a simple approach, but produces the wrong results, and is therefore not acceptable.  He is giving it as an example of something that doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, providing a seed and shuffling elements is not what i wanted, it wouldn't produce uniform selection.

Comment: Uniform is a slightly poor choice of word. It's often used to identify a probability distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Find what the indices would be if they were all equidistant, and round to the nearest integer.

```
int N = 100;

List<int> myList = Enumerable.Range(0, N).ToList();

double K = 53;

List<int> solutions=new List<int>();
for (int i=1;i<=K;i++)
{
    solutions.Add(myList[(int)Math.Round(i*(N/K)-1)]);
}

Console.WriteLine(solutions.Count);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", solutions));
```

See a sample at: [DEMO](https://ideone.com/3fbaqN)

EDIT: `Math.Floor` works better than `Math.Round` as `Math.Round` gives the wrong solution to N=5, K=3:

```
Math.Round->1,2,4
Math.Floor->0,2,4
```

See a sample at: [DEMO2](https://ideone.com/DqPvDW)

Comment: Compiler errors fixed. Was doing this on my phone...
added in parenthesis

Comment: Furthermore you're not guaranteed not to take the same element twice.

Comment: I believe you are if K is less then 101, in which case the question is nonsensical @PaulKertscher

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Forget my comment. I was way on the wrong track ;)

Comment: @PaulKertscher. No problem, I've been way off track far more times then on myself

Comment: Hi, the approach is good. The code doesn't compile, and it has index out of range exception but with small corrections it worked. Thanks a lot for very quick answer.

Comment: @NenadBirešev. No problem, glad to help. Vera Rind has already forced it up to scratch, so current answer should work.

Comment: Results give evenly spaced and not randomly spaced.

Comment: @jdweng because that's what OP requested. OP does not use the word "random" at all.

Comment: Hi it works after correcting the code. Thanks agian.

Comment: @NenadBirešev Is it ok that the results are "skewed high" instead of low, as in your example?  ie. `n=4`, `k=2`, the result is `1,3` instead of `0,2`?  Also for `n=4`, `k=3` you get unevenly distributed results, `0,2,3`?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Yeah, not without returning fewer than 3 results.  I just wanted to make sure that some of the edge cases were acceptable. I *do* like your answer, I wasn't trying to criticize it.

Comment: @BradleyUffner. No problem, thanks for your input :-)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is exactly same as line drawing algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm

In your case, you want to draw a line from (0, 0) to (20, 52)

Comment: That was a great insight, I hadn't realised that these amount to the same problem. Thanks, this was mighty helpful in writing a clean solution for my use case!

Answer (score -1):

You could still shuffle the list. Please see the follwing example

```
var n = 100;
var k = 53;

var originalList = GetListWithNElements(n);
var shuffledList = ShuffleList(originalList);
var firstKElements = GetFirstKElements(k, shuffledList);

[...]

List<int> GetListWithNElements(int n)
{
  return Enumerable.Range(0, n-1).ToList();
}

List<int> ShuffleList(List<int> originalList)
{
  List<int> copy = originalList.ToList();
  List<int> result = new List<int>();
  Random randomGenerator = new Random(314159); 

  while(copy.Any())
  {
    int currentIndex = randomGenerator.Next(copy.Count);
    result.Add(copy[currentIndex]);
    copy.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
  }

  return result;
}

List<int> GetFirstKElements(int k, List<int> shuffledList)
{
  return shuffledList.Take(k).ToList();
}
```

`Random` is initialized with a constant seed and hence will produce the very same sequence of *"random"* values each time, hence you will take the same elements each time.

Comment: Are you sure that this code will produce the expected result for `N=100; K=20` and `N=100;K=50`. I couldn't believe that because you're using a random generator to create the next index but the expected list is ordered. I'm pretty sure that sorting will not guarantee the distance request of each element to prev and next - but that's the part of the question that I didn't understand correctly.

Comment: @Verarind No, this wont produce the very same result, indeed. I read the OPs requirements as "the same results each time", but not the same result ze presented for 20 or 50.

Answer (score -2):

Try following :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int N = 100;
            {
                List<int> myList = Enumerable.Range(0, N - 1).ToList();
                int seed = 5;
                int numberOfItems = 50;
                List<int> results = TakeNItems(myList, seed, numberOfItems);
            }
        }
        static List<int> TakeNItems(List<int> data, int seed, int numberOfItems)
        {
            Random rand = new Random(seed);

            return data.Select((x,i) =>  new { x = x, index = i, rand = rand.Next()})
                .OrderBy(x => x.rand)
                .Take(numberOfItems)
                .OrderBy(x => x.index)
                .Select(x => x.x)
                .ToList();
        }
```

Comment: The resulting numbers are not uniformly distributed.  The OP's request has nothing to do with randomness.